# Integral involving a gaussian function

Tags: integration

Does $\int_{0}^{T} \frac{1}{T}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\left(t-t_{0}\right)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}e^{i\omega t}dt$ have a closed-form solution?

Comment: Does the error function count as closed form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an error function is allowed:

$$\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2} i \omega  \left(i \sigma ^2 \omega +2 t_0 \right)} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{i \sigma ^2 \omega + t_0 }{\sqrt{2}
   \sigma }\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{i \sigma ^2 \omega +t_0 -\text{T}}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)\right)}{2 \text{T}}$$

For

$$\int_0^T \frac{1}{T} \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{\left(t-t_{0}\right)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}} \cos \left( \omega t \right)\ dt$$

the answer is more complicated:

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} \omega  \left(\sigma ^2 \omega +2 i t_0 \right)}
   \left(-\text{erf}\left(\frac{-t_0 +i \sigma ^2 \omega }{\sqrt{2} \sigma
   }\right)+e^{2 i t_0 \omega } \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{\text{t0}+i \sigma ^2
   \omega }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{-i \sigma ^2 \omega
   -\text{t0}+\text{T}}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{i \sigma
   ^2 \omega -t_0+\text{T}}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)\right)}{4 \text{T}}$$

Otherwise I don't see how one can get a closed-form solution.

Comment: OK. But that gets me into troubles for physical interpretation (It is supposed to be the intensity of an electric field https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/346583/126819). What about $\int_{0}^{T} \frac{1}{T}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\left(t-t_{0}\right)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\cos\left(\omega t\right ) dt$ ?